# “Minutes later” vs. “a few minutes later”

Tags: word-usage, indefinite-articles, determiners, zero-article

Can I say this:

> I forgot about it minutes later.

Or do I have to say it this way instead:

> I forgot about it **a few** minutes later.

Comment: Why do you think this isn't OK to say?

Comment: In french we always have to say the equivalent of "a few" in that context. I wanted to make sure in english it was ok without. Because I used it and the answer of the person made me think she thought it took a long time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can. But usually the unadorned phrase *minutes later* (or *seconds later*) is reserved for emphasizing shortness of time in a way that "a few minutes later" doesn't really manage to convey, despite the fact that brevity would seem to be underscored by a qualifier like "a few" (which term is more likely to call attention to the inconsequentiality of the fact itself).